Is it safe to remove some Snaps from new LTS
Can you remove a few Snaps in the new 24.04 LTS without causing problem to your system. The Snaps I am wondering are snapd-desktop-integration, Firmware updater, ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap and Snap store. Can you do "sudo snap remove" for theese newly added and get away with it without damaging anything?

Do note if you get firmware updates, you'll have to boot another OS to install them, as you'll be removing the tool that Ubuntu uses to apply your machine's firmware updates.. ie. have you considered that?  How important is security to you, as you already imply you're happy with reducing your machines inbuilt security.

OK so firmware is off limits what about the rest of the snaps are those safe to remove? I will be doing a update from current LTS to the new one when it's ready not a fresh install that's why I'm curious. This bootstrap desktop says classic is also brand new not available in current LTS don't know what that is either.

Where did you get your list of snap packages from, as you mention ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap which is on the install media as it asks the TRY OR INSTALL question when booted, but is NOT normally found on installed systems (it's for sure not on my desktop system). You can install 24.04 LTS without snaps & use it... but every apps has benefits, so it's weighing up whether or not you need it (ie. last my first comment; where your machine firmware updates I've thought was rather obviously beneficial.. unless your machine is as old as my 2008 Dell I'm typing this on; ie. so old no updates.

https://res.cloudinary.com/canonical/image/fetch/f_auto,q_auto,fl_sanitize,w_819,h_592/https://dashboard.snapcraft.io/site_media/appmedia/2024/03/tryorinstall-1711102170.png  shows window that the ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap normally shows.. ie. it's found on install media but NOT installed systems...

Every snap package does something, however whether or not you'll miss it will depend on how your use your machine, and what you use your machine for.
Snaps you mention are
firmware updater
I'm using a 2008 Dell Optiplex currently; its so old that Dell, Intel etc no longer provide updates (they stopped after 10 years) so me removing that package would have no negative consequences for me. However is your machine that old? Do you dual boot? (ie. if firmware updates arrive, do you have another OS you can boot to apply fixes for your hardware!).  Only you can decide.
ubuntu desktop bootstrap
That's a snap package that provides the TRY or INSTALL question and is found on live install media. My own system does NOT have that installed, and I'd not expect to find it on any installed system, only the live system; so I see no problem with removing that (in fact wonder why you're asking about that! as if on an installed system I'd be exploring what you'd done to it to cause its install)

snapd-desktop-intergration
This page defines that app as

Provides a user session daemon used to provide a bridge between the user's session and snapd. Used for things like automatic theme installation.

How much does your desktop theming worry you? If you're like me and don't have problems with windows/apps not looking consistent, then it won't worry you. If you're removing all snap packages though, its very unlikely to be a problem, but again it's how you use your system & with what apps.
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS can install snap free
There are some 24.04 ISOs that will install a completely snap free 24.04 system (eg. Lubuntu 24.04 LTS using the minimal install option as example), where in Quality Assurance testing the check for that was execution of the snap list command; where the expected result was not "no snaps installed" but that the snap command itself had an error & suggested installing snapd (ie. that install is snapd free).
However, like everything in life, there are pros & cons.  Snap apps solve problems, are convenient & have some strengths, but some of us won't need them, whilst others will gain benefit from them.
Only you can decide.

If you want to know what the apps are, you can search for them on the snapcraft.io website where I've provided a link as example in this answer.  I've used 24.04 without any snapd infrastructure, but only short term, as I've written about before on answers about prior releases.. the real problems tend to appear LONG AFTER you've made the change - so I suggest documenting what changes you make to your system when you make them.

I have always removed snapd ever since they found their way into Ubuntu. I have in fact always done this as one of the first steps immediately installing Ubuntu on a system. As of today, I currently run 3 systems each with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, 22.04 LTS and 24.04 LTS and they all run like a charm.
If you do this the proper way, there will be no harm to the system whatsoever. Fear not, you are only making it better for your system the details of which are described on this github page - Why not snapd? . There is also a shell script that quickly nukes snapd for me, including installing the apt version of firefox, and gnome-software etc. This works in all LTS versions of ubuntu currently supported, including firmware updates that get pushed occasionally. No exceptions. Snaps are not the exclusive way to update firmware, neither are other dual-boot use OS-es. Ubuntu does well without neither for firmware updates.
